# Google API get bus station available lines

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to get a list of the nearest bus stops around a certain location along with which buses stop there. I can easily get nearby bus stops using the Google Places API but the response doesn't include which buses stop there. I want to extract the data that is visible when you click any bus stop (which can be seen below).

[image: Buses that stop at bus stop Google Maps]

Is there a way for me to extract (from the above example the numbers 52 and 452) using any Google API or even a 3rd party API?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @KévinVilelaPinto not yet. I will give this another try soon. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this @Cellydy?